# How can I parent a mesh to a vertex group?

Tags: constraints, parent

I want my eyelashes to follow a strip on the lid but I can only parent it to 3 vertices of that polystrip. I tried the "child of constraint" and selected the vertex group that I want to constraint/parent it to but then the eyelashes are all of a sudden not in the place anymore where I wanted them ... what is a normal or working way to do that? Must be a pretty common issue I suppose.

[image]

Edit: I added a screenshot. I moved the lashes a bit away from the place that it should be to show it better. I basically just want to stick it to its place and have it move with the lid in sculpt and edit mode.

Comment: Hi, maybe add a screenshot to clarify your example...

Comment: @m.ardito did that

Comment: Well I figured that I could instead also just spawn the hair directly on those faces, but I would still like to know how to parent or constraint or "stick" them instead (could be useful for other stuff too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Surface Deform` modifier to the eye lashes object. Then set the modifier target to the head. Click the 'Bind' button.

Now any shapekeys or armatures that affect verts in the head mesh, will also affect the eyebrow mesh.

[image]

If you make any edits to the amount of vertices in either mesh, you need to re-bind in the modifier.

It should be noted that the modifier doesn't use vertex groups like you asked for specifically. Instead, it maps the vertices of its parent mesh, to the closes points of the target mesh. Those points may not exactly align with vertices.
However, in your specific use case it seems like the eyelash mesh, and the eye lid mesh match almost exactly. So, this shouldn't cause any noticeable render issues.

Comment: Thanks man! That seems to be a good and easy way. Also probably useful for buttons on clothes and stuff like that.